# Cloud/Firebase function starts (is triggered) but doesn't run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is my test function:

```
export const onTest = functions
  .region('europe-west2')
  .runWith({
    memory: '256MB',
  })
  .firestore.document('pipeline/{docId}').onUpdate( (change, context) => {
    console.log('test');
    return 0;
  });
```

When I run it in the emulator, I have no issue: I modify a document of the `pipeline` collection in the firestore emulator, the onTest function is triggered and the logs are:

```
13:13:04 I function[onTest] Beginning execution of "onTest"
13:13:04 I function[onTest] test
13:13:04 I function[onTest] Finished "onTest" in ~1s
```

However, if I deploy this function and modify a doc in Firestore, those are the logs I get:

```
2020-06-26 12:56:42.990 CEST onTest lsklsthlminq Function execution started
2020-06-26 12:56:42.998 CEST onTest lsklsthlminq Function execution took 8 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

It looks like the function isn't executed, even though it's triggered.

Any hint?

Comment: if you skip  the onUpdate, and just let the print, does it work? I mean, that the issue is in the Firestore event rather than the print?

Answer (score 0):

When using Node.js versions 10 and later in Cloud Functions the `console.log` output might no longer be showing up in the output that you're looking at.

To show logs, you should use:

```
functions.logger.log("test");
```

Also see the [`firebase-functions` 3.7 release notes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v3.7.0).

Comment: Thanks Puff! it sounded promising, but it didn't do the trick :-(

Still the same result using `functions.logger` instead of `console` and upgrading to the latest packages  ("firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",  "firebase-functions": "^3.7.0")

Comment: Might it have to do with the fact I have 3 functions triggered by the same event (*update on firestore collection doc*)?
All the functions are triggered, but only one shows logs.

Comment: @PatrickM., did you figure out what did not work? In my case, 99.9% of the time it is working, but there is 0.1% once while that I have similar behavior.

Comment: sorry, can't remember :-/